# MySQL query builder PHP class

Tags: php, mysql, oop, class

I am building application which needs to have OOP style MySQL query builder. I want to be able to flexibly build complex queries using only PHP and to get resulting query string for execution with my own database driver.

Does anyone know of a good standalone query builder for PHP? Please note that I don't need database driver I need bare MySQL query builder class (preferably written with camel style function and variable names).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I took [Doctrine ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)

and modified it little bit to build SQL instead of [DQL](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html).

This works very nice and it able to construct complex queries.

**Edit:**
You can find my final stable implementation in [Stingle](https://bitbucket.org/alexamiryan/stingle) framework. Look at Db/QueryBuilder plugin.

Answer (score 5):

DSQL - Query Builder for PHP is exactly what you're looking for, no dependencies and has MIT license:

```
$query = new atk4\dsql\Query();
$query  ->table('employees')
    ->where('birth_date','1961-05-02')
    ->field('count(*)')
    ;
echo "Employees born on May 2, 1961: ".$query->getOne();
```

https://github.com/atk4/dsql

Documentation: http://dsql.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 2):

The *PhpToolCase* library has a stand-alone query builder tool that is quite easy and handy to use.

There is full join support aswell: http://phptoolcase.com/guides/ptc-qb-guide.html

And ya, it seems to be written with camel style function and variable names :)

Answer (score 0):

There is one version of query builder there (LGPL licenced). I haven't used it, but you might want to take a look at it, if it suits your purposes:
http://code.google.com/p/mysql-query-builder/

Comment: This very good one, but it lack ability to make left, inner, outer joins.

Comment: How can it be 'very good' yet not support joins? That's pretty much fundamental. It's also untouched for over 3 years, may have uncertain support on newer PHP versions.